# Storing local variable in std::map

Tags: c++

I have a class Message and a class Cache.
In Message::processMessage() fn. I create a instance of another class CacheRef(not shown below.)
then I call Cache::cacheData(cacheRef)

Now, in Cache class, I have a map which has its key as CacheReference. I store the ref that I passed to cacheData fn. in this map.

```
class Message
{
private:
Key m_key;

public:
  void processMessage(int a, int b, Cache *pCache)
   {
      CacheRef ref(a, b, m_key); //CacheRef is a class defined in same file
      //some char *data - do processing an dfill it!!
      pCache->cacheData(ref, data);

    }

}

class Cache
{
  public:
   void cacheData(CacheRef &ref, const char* data)
   {
     CacheDir *dir;
     std::map<<CacheRef, CacheDir*>::iterator it = m_dirs.find(ref);

      if(it == m_dirs.end())
     {
        dir = new CacheDir();
        m_dirs.insert(ref, dir);

      }
    }

    std::map<CacheRef, CacheDir*> m_dirs; //CacheDir is some class defined in the same file
}
```

Now, the code is working absolutely fine. But I have this concern(not sure!!) that I am storing some local variable in map, which which cease to exist as soon as processMessage()fn. exits. So, am I accessing some invalid memory, is it just by luck that this code is working.

If this is wrong, what is the best way to achieve this behaviour?
I don't have boost on my system, so can't use shared_ptr for anything.

Comment: Your code misses template parameters ... `std::map m_dirs` isn't going to work.

Comment: Can you show how the map m_dirs is templatized? Is the first template param a CacheRef& or a CacheRef ?

Comment: @etarion: The params were there but treated as HTML.  I fixed the formatting.

Comment: Thanks, alot. I was wondering where the parameters have gone!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the 1st template parameter is a CacheRef (and not a reference or pointer to a CacheRef) then ref will be copied into the map when you do the insert. Hence, you won't be storing a reference to a local stack variable.

As long as there is an appropriate copy constructor or assignment operator for CacheRef then this will work ok.

Comment: Ok, then this would stay for as long as class will exist. so, there is nothing wrong with this beahviour if I provide proper copy constructor and assignment operators in class CacheRef(Since, this class contains some pointers)

Comment: @user333422: Yes, that's right. Just make sure that `CacheRef` can be savely copied.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen Doyle pointed out, you are actually storing a copy of the `CacheRef` in the map, not a reference to the one passed to the `cacheData()` method.

Whether this causes a problem or not depends on the definition of the `CacheRef` class. If, for example, a `CacheRef` holds a pointer or a reference to the `Key` passed to the constructor, you will end up with an invalid pointer once the `Message` instance is destroyed.

By the way, since you are storing dynamically allocated objects of `CacheDir` in `Cache::m_dirs`, you should make sure to `delete` all values in the map in the `Cache::~Cache()` destructor to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks, yes i m taking care of deletion but just was wondering, whether i m using local variable or not.